# displaying images with different intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display an array of images that will replace each other but will have 0.5 sec of black screen between them.

For example array_img = ["im1","im2","im3"]
show im1 for 3 seconds, show a black screen for 0.5 sec, show im2 for 3 sec, black screen for 0.5 sec...

my code is
images_array is a global variable.
time_between_images = 3000 and is a global var
time_for_black_screen = 500 and is a global var

```
function displayImages(){
    for (i = 0; i < images_array.length; i++) {
        console.log(images_array[i]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("1");
            $('#exprBody').css('background-color', 'white');
            $('#picture_frame').append(images_array[i]);
        }, time_between_images)


        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("2");
            $("#picture_frame img:last-child").remove()
            $('#exprBody').css('background-color', 'black');
        }, time_for_black_screen)
    }
    console.log(images_array);

}
```

My html is simple

```
<body>
<div id="experiment_frame">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left_cat"></div><div id="right_cat"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="picture_frame" class="centered">
        <div id="exp_instruct"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I thought I should use setTimeout because I want to switch between the two tasks for each image in the array. IMG + black screen, IMG + black screen
but nothing is showing on my page.

The array

```
["<img src='/images/cute/1223.jpg'>", "<img src='/images/cute/1235.jpg'>", "<img src='/images/disgusted/8878.jpg'>", "<img src='/images/disgusted/8898.jpg'>", "<img src='/images/neutral/3321.png'>", "<img src='/images/neutral/3445.png'>"]
```

EDIT:

```
function displayImageIter(number) {
    $("body").toggleClass("whiteBody");
    $("#picture_frame").empty().append(images_array[number]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#picture_frame").empty();
        $("body").toggleClass("blackBody");
        setTimeout(function () {
            displayImageIter((number + 1) % images_array.length);
        }, time_for_black_screen)
    }, time_between_images)
}
```

For some reason what I have with this code is
IMG white background
blank screen white for 0.5 sec
IMG black background
blank screen white for 0.5 sec

Comment: Can you please include the data tree of the `images_array` variable? Cannot be 100% sure that this is a viable variable to pass to `.append()` in jQuery

Comment: added  in an edit to original post

Comment: A few points: If you set all your timeouts in a loop, they will all execute one after another. For example assuming you have 5 images, the console should output straight away: "<img>", "<img>", "<img>", "<img>", "<img>" then in 500 milliseconds: "2", "2", "2", "2" ,"2" then in another 2500 milliseconds: "1", "1", "1", "1", "1".

In theory you should be seeing 5 images after 3 seconds of executing the code.

Comment: i am seeing nothing, but that is good to know

Comment: `toggleClass` adds the class if it is absent and removes it if it is present. So don't use `$("body").toggleClass("whiteBody");` and use `$("body").toggleClass("blackBody");` instead. If the body initially has a `blackBody` class, then first time it will be removed, and second time added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following simplified code:

```js
function displayImage(number) {
    $("#picture_frame").empty().append(images_array[number]).css('background-color', 'white');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#picture_frame").empty().css('background-color', 'black');
        setTimeout(function () {
            displayImage((number + 1) % images_array.length);
        }, time_for_black_screen)
    }, time_between_images)
}

const images_array = ["FIRST IMAGE", "SECOND IMAGE", "THIRD IMAGE"];
const time_between_images = 3000;
const time_for_black_screen = 500;

displayImage(0);
```

```css
#picture_frame {width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: white}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picture_frame"></div>
```

Answering your comment:

a) To change the parent div background just use:

```
$("#picture_frame").empty().append(images_array[number]);
$("#parent_div").css('background-color', 'white');
```

b) To stop this loop you could use some flag and set it to false after 15 minutes:

```
function displayImage(number) {
    $("#picture_frame").empty().append(images_array[number]).css('background-color', 'white');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#picture_frame").empty().css('background-color', 'black');
        setTimeout(function () {
            //continue only if flag is true
            if (flag) displayImage((number + 1) % images_array.length);
        }, time_for_black_screen)
    }, time_between_images)
}

const images_array = ["FIRST IMAGE", "SECOND IMAGE", "THIRD IMAGE"];
const time_between_images = 3000;
const time_for_black_screen = 500;

let flag = true;

displayImage(0);

//used 15 seconds here for simplicity
setTimeout(() => flag = false, 15000);
```

Comment: two questions. 
a) it should be possible to set the entire body of the screen black and not just that div?
b) say I want to add another task. after 15 mins stop that loop and continue only after a key press. Do I need to had another setTimeout around the entire code?

Comment: thank you for some reason the black stuff is not working on my computer but i'll try to debug it. I am trying to set the body, and what I get is a black white iteration in the background of the images.

Comment: @Quantico you can ask a separate question and I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="img0"></a>
<a class="img1"></a>
<a class="img2"></a>
<script>
  var elArr = [];
  // here get the els that you wanna to display img
  elArr.push(document.querySelector('.img0'));
  elArr.push(document.querySelector('.img1'));
  elArr.push(document.querySelector('.img2'));
  // here is the img src and it's interval
  var imgArr = [
    { src: 'a', interval: 3000 },
    { src: 'b', interval: 2000 },
    { src: 'c', interval: 1000 },
  ];
  //  if you wanna auto display unknown number imgs, set a variable to count the whole interval
  var sumInterval = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
    // the first interval is 3000, second is 5000, third is 6000
    sumInterval += imgArr[i].interval;
    setTimeout(function () {
      elArr[i].innerHTML = imgArr[i].src;
      // if is the last img, set an interval and then do the callback
      if (i == imgArr.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          alert('now screen shall be black');            
        }, 500)
      }
    }, sumInterval);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like a possible solution, but you should add an explanation as this is not easy to read for beginners.

Comment: I'm not good at it English, so it may hard to add a comment with English